# Running c++ in linux

Tags: c++, linux

I have saves my code in the name: clus.cpp
when I open the terminal and run

```
 g++ clusters.cpp
```

the output is:

```
 fatal error: libspp.h: No such file or directory
```

It is the same for any other code, with different libraries. Does anyone know how can I solve the problem?

Comment: You need to install the development packages for the 3rd party libraries you use. If there exists no prebuilt packages for your distribution, then you have to download, built and install the libraries yourself.

Comment: How can I check if prebuilt there is packages for my distribution or not? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Use your distributions package tools? Search for the libraries, if there are packages with `dev` or similar in their names. If you don't know how to search for that, then I suggest post a generic question about in on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), where you give more details about e.g. your Linux distribution.

Comment: I did but I got negative score @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0):

This compiler error is practically telling you that there is no such file libspp.h on your computer.

This means you have to install the library that contains this file.

If this is the same for every other code that you write just remove this header from your file. The `#include "libspp.h"` and try with a simple program like printing "Hello world".